# Place Order Api Problem

Tags: magento2

carts/mine/payment-information?api=1
I am using this

---

```
<?php 
$addressInformation                        = new \stdClass();
$addressInformation->cart_id               = $quoteId;
$shipping_address                          = new \stdClass();
$shipping_address->region                  = $addressInfo['region'];
$shipping_address->country_id              = $addressInfo['country_id'];
$shipping_address->street                  = array($addressInfo['street']);
$shipping_address->telephone               = $addressInfo['telephone'];
$shipping_address->postcode                = $addressInfo['postcode'];
$shipping_address->city                    = $addressInfo['city'];
$shipping_address->firstname               = $addressInfo['firstname'];
$shipping_address->lastname                = $addressInfo['lastname'];
$shipping_address->email                   = $addressInfo['email'];
$shipping_address->save_in_address_book    = 0;
$addressInformation->billing_address       = $shipping_address;
$addressInformation->paymentMethod         = new \stdClass();
$addressInformation->paymentMethod->method = $this->_payment_method;
```

---

This gives an error `unable to place order try again later`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass below data

```
{
    "cartId": "1528",
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "inchoo_stripe",
        "additional_data": {
            "stripe_card_id": "new",
            "cc_last4": "1111",
            "cc_token": "#####",
            "cc_type": "VI",
            "cc_exp_year": "2017",
            "cc_exp_month": "2",
            "save_card": "true"
        },
        "extension_attributes": {}
    },
    "billingAddress": {
        "countryId": "US",
        "regionId": "19",
        "regionCode": "GA",
        "region": "Georgia",
        "customerId": "8616",
        "street": ["test"],
        "company": "Nb",
        "telephone": "7878787878",
        "postcode": "30002",
        "city": "test",
        "firstname": "aalpha",
        "lastname": "testing",
        "save_in_address_book": false
    }
}
```

Make sure before that shipping address save.

Comment: hi Address of billing and shipping is in  quote_address table. Now I am using
this API::http://local.marketplace.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information?api=1
REQUEST BODY ::
{"cart_id":"1199","billing_address":{"region":"Delhi","country_id":"IN","street":["Delhi"], "telephone":"9910146456","postcode":"110092","city":"Delhi", "firstname":"Taslim","lastname":"Waris","email":"taslim.waris@gmail.com","save_in_address_book":0},"paymentMethod":{"method":"hdfc"}}

RESPONSE ::
{
  "message": "The requested Payment Method is not available."
}

Comment: is that payment method available? If available then no need to pass any argument?  so try with other payment method like cash on delivery and try it.

Comment: YES PaymentMethod hdfc is available...I am not passing paymentMethod this gives error.

Comment: @TaslimWaris i think you need to pass some argument into that payment method. you can check which argument pass into web browser when you click on place order,check in console which argument pass.

Comment: have you checked with cash on delivery payment method?